# Shortcut for operator context panel (redo panel) in 2.8?

Tags: workflow, shortcut, properties, operator

[image: Context Menu]

Is there a shortcut or a plugin that helps expands this context menu automatically? This extra mouse maneuver and click is quite exhausting in a bigger project when compared to before 2.8. Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). Once you expand it, it should stay that way for all new objects. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Just press <kbd>F9</kbd> or go to *Edit > Adjust Last Operation*, which displays the *Redo Panel* a.k.a. *Operator Panel* as a simple pop-up window after using any operator:

[image]

Quoting from the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation):

> After an operation is complete you can tweak the parameters of the operation afterwards. In editors that support it, there is a “head-up display” panel in the bottom left based on the last performed operation; dependent on mode and context. Alternatively, you can create a pop-up with <kbd>F9</kbd> which does the same thing.